# How to display unicode text on flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Inside the text widget I am using a special character in the following way:

```
Text('↻');
```

This works fine on Android and IOS, but on Web a ☒ appears instead.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Git issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77465) is still open.

Comment: Thank you Yeasin. Do you know any workaround?